# How to prove that $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n+1} \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{k-2}\frac{n-\ell}{n}$ converges to $\sqrt{\pi/2}$?

Tags: limits, summation

Consider $$
X_k =\prod_{\ell=1}^{k-2}\frac{n-\ell}{n}
\ \textrm{ for every } 2\leqslant k\leqslant n+1.
$$

How can you prove the following? 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} X_k= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

A heuristic argument replaces $\frac{n-\ell}{n}$ by $e^{-\ell}$ and the sum by an integral. How can this (or another method) be made rigorous?

Comment: looks like some tricky application of CLT may do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the change of variable $k=n+1-i$ and some simple algebraic manipulations, one sees that the $n$th sum $S_n$ is
$$
S_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\frac{n!}{n^n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^i}{i!}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\frac{n!}{n^n}\mathrm e^n\mathbb P(Z_n\leqslant n-1),
$$
where $Z_n$ is a random variable with Poisson distribution of parameter $n$. Thus, $Z_n$ is distributed as $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$, where the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. with Poisson distribution of parameter $1$. The central limit theorem applied to the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ shows that $T_n=(Z_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ is asymptotically standard normal when $n\to\infty$, and in particular,
$$
\mathbb P(Z_n\leqslant n-1)=1-\mathbb P(T_n\geqslant0)\to1-\tfrac12=\tfrac12.
$$
This asymptotics, together with Stirling's approximation formula $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/\mathrm e)^n$, implies that $S_n\to\sqrt{\pi/2}$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: "This" is "universally true" (as you say) as long as "this" corresponds to [the precise and rigorous definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) of asymptotic equivalence which is meant in my post (the trouble here being that the symbol $\sim$ is sometimes used with a less precise meaning, in which case, as you say, more caution would be needed).

Comment: Except that if $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=0$, then $g(x)\sim f(x)$ is quite wrong. (Exercise: assume that $g(x)=0$ for every $x$ and that $g(x)\sim k(x)$ when $x\to x_0$, then $k(x)=0$ for every $x$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.)

Comment: ...anything but itself, that is.

Comment: Not. At. All. The whole point of asymptotics analysis is to compare bunches of functions with the same limit. Thus one wants to say, for example, that $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto\sin(x)$ are roughly *the same* when $x\to0$ but that $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ are not.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks.